# Recurrent Firebase message from console, only send the first message but not the second

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, message, messaging

I'm using the Firebase console for send a recurrent message each saturday.
I had configure it as the image, and the first message sent & arrived correctly to the devices.
But at the next saturday, the message did not arrive...
[image: Firebase console]
I have done a lot of test (changing the "each week" for "each 7 days" for example) but I only get him to send only the first message.
what am I doing wrong?